# TypeError: afterGet(): Argument #2 ($result) must be of type

Tags: magento2

TypeError: Mstore\ProductsList\Plugin\TotalsPlugin::afterGet(): Argument #2 ($result) must be of type Mstore\ProductsList\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface, Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/app/code/Mstore/ProductsList/Plugin/TotalsPlugin.php:76

```
<?php

namespace Mstore\ProductsList\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class TotalsPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var TotalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory;
    /**
     * @var ItemFactory
     */
    private $itemFactory;
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    private $date;
    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    private mixed $discountPercent;

    /**
     * TotalsPlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param TotalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory
     * @param ItemFactory $itemFactory
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param TimezoneInterface $date
     */
    public function __construct(
        TotalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory,
        ItemFactory                         $itemFactory,
        ProductFactory                      $productFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface                $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        TimezoneInterface                   $date
    )
    {
        $this->totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory = $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory;
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * After get items.
     *
     * @param GuestCartTotalRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param TotalsInterface $result
     * @return TotalsInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(
        GuestCartRepositoryInterface $subject,
        TotalsInterface              $result
    ) {
        /** @var TotalsItemInterface $item */
        foreach ($result->getItems() as $item) {
            $id = $item->getItemId();
            $product = $this->getProductById($id);
            $sku = $_product->getSku();

            $image = $product ? $product->getImage() : "";
            $specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice() ?? 0;
            $specialFromDate = $product->getSpecialFromDate() ?? "";
            $specialToDate = $product->getSpecialToDate() ?? "";
            $originalPrice = $product->getPrice() ?? 0;
            $brandName = $product->getTestingBrandName() ?? "";
            $productLinks = $product->getProductLinks()??[];
            
            $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();

            if (!$extensionAttributes) {
                $extensionAttributes = $this->totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();
            }

            $extensionAttributes->setProductSku($sku);
            $extensionAttributes->setProductImage($image);
            $extensionAttributes->setOriginalPrice($originalPrice);
            $extensionAttributes->setSpecialPrice($specialPrice);
            $extensionAttributes->setSpecialPriceFrom($specialFromDate);
            $extensionAttributes->setSpecialPriceTo($specialToDate);
            $extensionAttributes->setTestingBrandName($brandName);
            $extensionAttributes->setProductLinks($productLinks);
            $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }


}



<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="product_skus" type="Mstore\ProductsList\Plugin\TotalsPlugin"/>
    </type>
```

Comment: Add your whole code for plugin and di.xml

Comment: updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:
First check, if simple log is working for you.

```
<?php

namespace Mstore\ProductsList\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartRepositoryInterface;

class TotalsPlugin
{

     /**
     * After get items.
     *
     * @param GuestCartTotalRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CartInterface $result
     * @param string $cartId
     * @return CartInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(GuestCartRepositoryInterface $subject, CartInterface $result, $cartId):CartInterface
    {
    // Add log here to test, if it is working
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtension::setProductSku() in /var/www/html/app/code/Mstore/ProductsList/Plugin/TotalsPlugin.php:99

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: yes thankssssssss